# illusion that normal life has returned

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a story from *The Economist*. The title of the story is "white lies: the scarcity of fake tan reveals some naked truths".

In this part, the author talks about self-tanners are in short supply because of a lack of ethoxydiglycol, an ingredient which makes the product spread evenly on skin.

> Eventually ethoxydiglycol will be plentiful again, just like loo paper and sanitising wipes before it, to give us the illusion not only of glowing skin, but that normal life has returned...

I can understand why the author writes people can have an "illusion" that their "glowing skin" comes back, given they have self-tanners help them look radiant again.

But why would people have the "illusion" that "normal life has returned"? If people can use self-tanners again, I think it is true normal life has returned.

Comment: Only that one aspect of normal life has returned. Other aspects of normal life may not have returned.

Comment: I think it's meant to be tongue-in-cheek,  and not meant to be taken literally.  Life is back to normal, mostly, except perhaps for those who complain about trivialities like a lack of self-tanning products.

Comment: This follows the commonly expressed belief that life will never return to pre-COVID normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire article isn't about fake tan. That is just one indicator of much bigger issues.

Some people view the problems currently facing the world through a very narrow lens. There are product shortages, personnel shortages, inflation, and serious supply-chain issues that are blamed on various underlying causes (let's not mention specifics here so as not to politically divide people). As a result of inflation, some people face losing their homes. But some people only notice things that affect them personally - in this case, a shortage of fake tan. Literally, a cosmetic item that would be viewed by many as immaterial compared to the bigger issues.

The suggestion is that such people would think the world had returned to normal as soon as their fake tan is available again, which would be an 'illusion' because the availability of a product that makes you look like an orange oompa loompa doesn't really solve the world's financial crisis.